# Freemarker: Reproduce XML

Tags: xml, transform, freemarker

Folks,
I am working on a freemarker template that needs to reproduce parts of the input XML tree.

I would love to have a macro that I could invoke as follows:

```
<@renderTree node=node namespace="ns"/>
```

Anyone have something like this handy?

Thanks.

-Raj

Answer (score 1):

Freemarker has a special hash key for this: @@markup. So, my example above:

```
<@renderTree node=node namespace="ns"/>
```

Where variable "node" contains an XML node, will be written as:

```
${ node[ "@@markup" ] }
```

More info here: [Freemarker Manual XML processing](http://freemarker.sourceforge.net/docs/xgui_imperative_formal.html)